# Twilio Say "Call is being recorded" for the person caller and after the customer picks up

Tags: java, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I have it currently set up where if a twilio number is called, the call will be recorded and the person that dialed the number will hear "This call may be recorded for quality assurance purposes" before hearing any ringing. The response for the hook is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Say>
    This call may be recorded for quality assurance purposes.
  </Say>
  <Dial record="record-from-answer"
     recordingStatusCallback="CALL_RECORD_URL"
     recordingStatusCallbackEvent="completed">
    <Number url="CALL_PLAYBACK_URL">
      +1yyyyyyyyyy
    </Number>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

It is also set up where the "CALL_PLAYBACK_URL" returns the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Say>
    This call may be recorded for quality assurance purposes.
  </Say>
</Response>
```

When I attempt to call the twilio number, the person that is CALLING the number gets the correct message before hearing any ringing, but the customer picking up the number does not hear anything after hitting accept, as the call instantly gets connected. Is there anything that I am missing with this? Should the value of the `url` for the Number part be the full url or just the path (`https://www.example.com/callbackurl` vs `/callbackurl`)? I have tried both with no success

I've looked at other ones such as [Twilio Say "Call is being recorded" after customer answers call from web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54991648/twilio-say-call-is-being-recorded-after-customer-answers-call-from-web-applica)
and https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/ivr-screening-java-servlets

Comment: Check the Twilio Console Debugger, to see if you have any errors, https://www.twilio.com/console/debugger?quickDate=72.

Comment: I did not see any errors in the console for the endpoints

Comment: After further testing, I think the Say command is running immediately instead of waiting for the customer to pick up. I tested by adding a 10 second pause before the Say, and I could hear the message if I picked up the phone before the 10 second delay ended

Comment: That isn’t typical behavior. It is possible the dialed number is answering the call immediately and then playing false ring back to the caller. Not common but happens for CPaaS providers when they execute code to route the call.

Comment: Is there a setting or something for that? Or a completely different method to run a Say before connecting the call between two people

Comment: Unfortunately, it is the terminating provider which has this behavior. Twilio support would be able to verify this is the case if you shared a few recent CallSID's, https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223180488-What-is-a-Call-SID-, exhibiting this issue.